# Is it safe to access properties of objects using the ._doc method in Mongoose/MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, authentication, mongoose

If I saved an user object in mongodb, I usually access the properties like below,
`const { _id, username, email } = user`

But I have seen some people use ._doc private property to access objects as below,
`const { _id, username, email } = user._doc`

My question is since ._doc property is a private property, is it unsafe using that to access a object rather than accessign it directly?

I use both of the method, but I never had any problem.